# How to use "this" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mootools, this

I have this piece of code:

```
this.json.each(function(obj, index) {
    var li = new Element('li');
    var a = new Element('a', {
        'href': '#',
        'rel': obj.id,
        events: {
            'click': function(e) {

                this.doSteps(this.step + 1); // <-- causing issue

            }
        }   
    });
    var img = new Element('img', {
        'src': imgd + obj.img,
        'alt': obj.name                        
    });
    img.inject(a);
    a.inject(li);
    li.inject(ul);
});
```

I get an error of "this.doSteps is not a function" in the console. Can somebody please help me with this and explain the resolution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try capturing it in a closure:

```
var li = new Element('li');
var _self = this;
var a = new Element('a', {
    'href': '#',
    'rel': obj.id,
    events: {
        'click': function(e) {

            _self.doSteps(_self.step + 1); // <-- causing issue

        }
    }   
});
```

Comment: +1 I think this is preferred to `.bind` as it's cheaper, though where performance is not critical, you can do either dependent on your readability preferences.

Comment: A very good reference for javascript objects including the use of closures is: http://helephant.com/2008/08/17/how-javascript-objects-work/

Comment: This answer is correct, but really does not fit MooTools' philosophy. You should use `bind`, as shown by @OskarKrawczyk in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993472/how-to-use-this-in-javascript/7994076#7994076).

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind `this`, so the scope of the function is referring to the right `this`.

```
'click': function(e) {
    this.doSteps(this.step + 1);
}.bind(this)
```

This is the MooTools way.

Answer (score 0):

On the line causing the issue `this` refers to the object the function belongs to, i.e. to `events`, which indeed doesn't have any member named `doSteps`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass this in a each function with ,this.

```
this.json.each(function(obj, index) {


    }, this);
```

Answer (score -1):

try to use `e` the element you're currently working on

```
this.json.each(function(obj, index) {
    var li = new Element('li');
    var a = new Element('a', {
        'href': '#',
        'rel': obj.id,
        events: {
            'click': function(e) {

                e.doSteps(e.step + 1); // <-- here the e from the function is your element

            }
        }   
    });
    var img = new Element('img', {
        'src': imgd + obj.img,
        'alt': obj.name                        
    });
    img.inject(a);
    a.inject(li);
    li.inject(ul);
});
```

Comment: dosteps() not declared in the scope so i just guessed